# Invoking a flow from APEX to send email

Tags: flow, schedulebatch

We are writing a batch schedulable class which retrieves all the overdue task and send email to the contact in assigned to.

The problem is while invoking emails from APEX we have certain governor limits. So we are planning use a flow to send email. Any ideas how to send email using flows and invoking the flow from APEX?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new Object named as Message__C ,having field's to,from,subject,body,status. Now create a workflow rule,when created and send email to fields present in Message object.

Now whenver in a trasaction you wanna send email,create an instance of Message object,populating all fields and inserting it. It will send your mail.

We can invoke limited number of emails via APEX, but via this approach you can send as many mails as many records created during transaction.

Workflow daily email is 100X higher than via API.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across same kind of problem. I created a flow to send an email using flow variables like below in email core action.
[image: Edit "Send Email" core action]

And then I have invoked the above flow from the apex.

```
`Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
 params.put('emailIdsString','abc@gmail.com,bbc@yahoo.com');
 params.put('emailBody',  'Test Body');
 params.put('emailSubject',  'Test Subject');
 Flow.Interview.Send_Email_to_OpptyOwner Send_EmailFlow = new 
 Flow.Interview.Send_Email_to_OpptyOwner(params);
 Send_EmailFlow.start();`
```

Send_Email_to_OpptyOwner is the API name of the flow.
It is working fine for me.
Refer below links as well
https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/10/26/calling-flow-from-apex/